# Error Deploying Firestore Function with a space in the name of a collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function that updates an Algolia Search index whenever a new document is created in my Firestore. Everything seems to start well but then at the very end, it errors out. I've been through the docs and it feels like my syntax is correct so I'm not sure what to do at this point. The Cloud Functions log don't point to anything and just echo the error that I received below

**Error Message:**

```
=== Deploying to 'test-ffdbb'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (1.25 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating function onProductCreated...
!  functions[onProductCreated]: Deployment error.
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (onProductCreated)
```

**My Code:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

// App ID and API Key are stored in functions config variables
const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app_id;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.api_key;

const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = "Firestore";
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

// Update the search index every time a blog post is written.
exports.onProductCreated = functions.firestore
.document("Product Catalog/{id}")
.onCreate(event => {
  const product = event.data.data();
  product.objectID = event.params.postId;

  const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
  return index.saveObject(product);
});
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.8.2",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.24.5",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be the space in path segment `Product Catalog`.  When I remove it, the function deploys successfully:

```
exports.onProductCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("ProductCatalog/{id}") // <== space removed
  .onCreate(event => {...});
```

Also note that the wildcard in your path is `id` and in the code you reference `postId`:

```
  product.objectID = event.params.postId;
```

Comment: So in my Firestore, I have a Collection titled "Product Catalog", which is why I referenced it as such. Good to know that even though you can do it in the console, you can't reference it back that way. The function was deployed but it's not executing and I think it has something to do with the {id}. I'll troubleshoot that separately. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: I was missing a '/' in my path and this answer helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: It also throws the same error if your mistakenly try to reference a collection or property on your object from the document path.

Comment: Mine was a longer segment "/proxies/countries/united states/states/.../cities/...   I went ahead and parameterised united states to {country}

```
 if (context.params.country !== 'united states') {
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in the Firebase CLI deployment.  Spaces in collection ids and document ids are perfectly valid in Firestore, and the deploy shouldn't fail if there's a space present.  I've logged a bug internally with the Firebase team on this, and you should feel free to log anything that seems like a bug yourself [at this page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).