# Error while using spaces in collection name in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a trigger on the following collection in my firestore db, when i deploy the function i get the following error:-

> !functions[testFunction]: Deployment error.
>   Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write@firestore.googleapis.com (testFunction)
>   Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
>       firebase deploy --except functions
>   Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Here is my function:

```
exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('/hospitals/Sidra Outpatient Hospital/users/noKW8jeJLLUeN1MTerHbCbGDzT72').onWrite((event) => {});
```

I did try with a collection that does not have spaces and it successfully deployed.

Comment: yes it does not work with spaces

Comment: @Peter Haddad is there an alternative or should I change my way of naming the collections?

Comment: Can you trying replacing the collection name with a wildCard? `.document('/hospitals/{hospital}/users/noKW8jeJLLUeN1MTerHbCbGDzT72')`

Comment: I believe this is a bug with deployment.  Spaces in collection and document ids are valid in Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

This wont work:

```
 exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('/hospitals/Sidra Outpatient Hospital/users/noKW8jeJLLUeN1MTerHbCbGDzT72').onWrite((event) => {});
```

As it contains space, and you cant use space when referencing to a location. To solve this you need to remove the spaces.

Also instead of this `noKW8jeJLLUeN1MTerHbCbGDzT72`, you can use wildcard example :

```
 exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('/hospitals/SidraOutpatientHospital/users/{pushid}').onWrite((event) => {});
```

This way everytime anything is changed under a pushid onWrite will get triggered.

Comment: Spaces in document ids are valid.  You can see for yourself if you try to create one in the Firebase console.  I think this is a bug with deployment, and I'm going to file one internally.

Comment: check this answer from Bob https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040239/7015400 @DougStevenson

Comment: So, that's not really an answer.  It's an observation and workaround (like yours).  If it's not an option to remove the spaces from collection and document name (for example, if they're very well established throughout a large product), you're stuck.

Comment: yes I agree, I just linked it here if you want to comment there