# How to access firestore document with space character in between (how to escape space character?)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do we access a document or collection with a space in between?

For example:

```
export const onStore = 
functions.firestore
.document('Stores/Test Store/{nameID}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        })
});
```

I've tried &nbsp, %20 and escape \ with a space, but all of them don't work. Leaving it as space itself will return me an error on firebase deploy.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the Firebase CLI that is there for several months, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039040/error-deploying-firestore-function-with-a-space-in-the-name-of-a-collection. You may change your document name to something without spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Renaud
I'll use curly braces to reference them for now. I can't change all the documents now, as it's a live app already.