# ReferenceError: chapter is not defined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a notification to a specific device once a document has been created in my collection "My Hero Academia". When I try to deploy the function, I get the following error -

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

ReferenceError: chapter is not defined
```

The code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var msgData;
var token = "####";

exports.offerTrigger = functions.firestore.document(
    'My Hero Academia'/{chapter}
    ).onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
        msgData = snapshot.data();
        var payload = {
            "notifications": {
                "title": "A new chapter has been released",
                "body": "Read chapter " + msgData.number + " now!",
                "sound": "default"
            }
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload).then((response) => {
            console.log('Pushed notification');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    })
```

Obviously, I've hidden my token. As the error says, chapter isn't defined. But isn't {chapter} used to refer to the new document that will be created?

Edit:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":13,"message":"INTERNAL"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"user2312@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":{},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/dmscraper-c91da/locations/us-central1/functions/offerTrigger"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
functions.firestore.document(
    'My Hero Academia'/{chapter}
    ).onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
```

into this:

```
functions.firestore.document('My Hero Academia/{chapter}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
```

You should have `'` also over `{chapter}`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#wildcards-parameters

Comment: Tried this, now I'm getting "Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        offerTrigger"

Comment: can u check the `functions` section in firebase console, it will have the logs there with more details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039040/error-deploying-firestore-function-with-a-space-in-the-name-of-a-collection

Comment: Oh, that worked. Thanks a lot for the help man. I've been stuck with this for 2 days. :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the project!