# Firebase Functions Deployment Failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy my firebase function called `onFollowUser` however, it has been constantly failing to launch. I have the Blaze plan currently and this is the error message:

```
⚠  functions[onFollowUser(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (__gcf__.us-central1.onFollowUser)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        onFollowUser


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:onFollowUser


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Here is my complete `index.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onFollowUser = 
functions
.firestore
.document('/Followers/{userID}/User Follower/{followerID}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log(snapshot.data());
});
```

I have spotted the error... My database is located in Europe-central, however, for some reason, it is deploying to US-central... How can I change this? The ID of my project which it says it is deploying to is correct.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Edit: Even though I get this failing message, I can see the function on my console :
[image]

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: "My database is located in Europe-central, however, for some reason, it is deploying to US-central... " There should be no problem to have a Firestore DB in one location and a Cloud Function in another location. See the following link to change the region: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370109/3371862

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec and Mike, it is now deploying

Comment: This might be a funny answer... I was deploying correctly, but then, I started having the same issue. After spending 4 hours trying to fix it... I found out that my billing account was suspended, because my last payment of $0.01 failed. I just added a new payment method and my deploying started working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue, see: [Error Deploying Firestore Function with a space in the name of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039040/error-deploying-firestore-function-with-a-space-in-the-name-of-a-collection)

Rename the a collections so that they do not includes spaces, rather use camel case, dashes or underscores.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

exports.onFollowUser = 
functions
.firestore
.document('/Followers/{userID}/User-Follower/{followerID}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log(snapshot.data());
    return;
});
```

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: If its showing in your functions list then it did deploy at some stage. Try triggering it and check the logs to see if you get a better error message.Another thing to try is to change .document('/Followers/{userID}/User Follower/{followerID}') to .document('Followers/{userID}/User Follower/{followerID}').

Comment: What do you mean by removing the preceeding?

Comment: Edited my comment, hit the enter key instead of backspace.

Comment: Ok.. working on it

Comment: No... still no luck.. It tells me that the function has failed to deploy but I see it on my firebase console

Comment: The error message doesn't say it failed to deploy, it says it failed to configure the trigger provider. That implies that it is not a deployment issue but rather a code issue. I noticed your have a space in a collection name, try escaping it maybe? Better solution: don't use spaces, use camel case or dashes or underscores, something that doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: I edited my question and found the possible issue

Comment: The space in the subcollection name is indeed the problem.

Comment: Ok... how can I fix this? Would I need to change all the occurrences of this?

Comment: Yes you should follow Mike's advice: "use camel case or dashes or underscores". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370109/3371862

Comment: @RenaudTarnec would this be an eligible name : ```.document('/Followers/{userID}/User-Follower/{followerID}')```

Comment: This is a know issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039040/error-deploying-firestore-function-with-a-space-in-the-name-of-a-collection, no real solution but the difficult one to rename all occurrences. Maybe try this first: .document("/Followers/{userID}/User\ Follower/{followerID}")

Comment: "would this be an eligible name : .document('/Followers/{userID}/User-Follower/{followerID}')" -> it should be.

Comment: @Mike: please adapt your answer in such a way we can upvote it.

Comment: Yes @Mike, edit your answer please :)